# Solving Ax=b with numpy linalg python raise LinAlgError('Incompatible dimensions')

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, least-squares

I am trying to solve Ax = b for x.

A is a sparse matrix; x is unknown, and a b is a np.array.

```
print(type(matrix_a))
print(type(vector_c))

print("Matrix A Shape  -- %s " %str(matrix_a.shape))
print("vector c shape -- %s " %len(vector_c))

#xx = np.array([1],dtype=np.float32)

vec_c = np.insert(vector_c,0,1)
print("Update Vector c shape -- %s "% len(vec_c))

new_matrix = matrix_a.todense()
new_matrix_T = new_matrix.transpose()

x = np.linalg.lstsq(new_matrix_T,vec_c)
```

yields the following output.

> Matrix A Shape  -- (48002, 7651)
>   vector c shape -- 48001
>   Update Vector C shape -- 48002

Traceback (most recent call last):   File

> "/Users/*removed*/PycharmProjects/hw2/main.py", line 139, in 
>       main()   File "/Users/*removed*/PycharmProjects/hw2/main.py", line 65, in main
>       b1 = st.fit_parameters(A1, c)   File "/Users/*removed*/PycharmProjects/hw2/hw3_part1.py", line 191, in
>   fit_parameters
>       x = np.linalg.lstsq(new_matrix_T,vec_c)   File "/Users/*removed*/.conda/envs/hw2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 1984, in lstsq
>       raise LinAlgError('Incompatible dimensions') numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Incompatible dimensions

Comment: Can you post what `vec_c.shape` (not `len`) and `vector_c.shape` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're transposing your matrix `matrix_a` which is shape `M, N = 48002, 7651` to shape `N, M = 7651, 48002`. But the problem is that your vector is shape `M = 48002,` and  [`np.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) takes dimensions `(a.shape=(M, N), b.shape=(M,)`. Because of your transpose, you are passing dimensions `(a.shape=(N, M), b.shape=(M,))`.

Solution? Don't transpose `matrix_a`.